# What does the video output stream details from ffmpeg mean?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

When you run `ffmpeg -i` with the video file as input parameter, ffmpeg returns some details of the stream type, like codec, bitrate and resolution. What does the other data mean - "tbr", "tbn" and "tbc"? From my examples below, you can see that they vary a lot.

`Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc`

`Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480, 22050 tbr, 22050 tbn, 44100 tbc`

`Stream #0.1: Video: wmv3, yuv420p, 1280x720, 4000 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc`

Secondary question: why is not bitrate always shown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see is the reciprocal of the time stamp bases used in FFmpeg and the en/decoders. I can't explain it better, therefore just [quoting the FFmpeg mailing list](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/What-does-the-output-of-ffmpeg-mean-tbr-tbn-tbc-etc-td941538.html):

> **tbn** is the time base in AVStream that has come from the container, I 
>   think. It is used for all AVStream time stamps.
>
> **tbc** is the time base in AVCodecContext for the codec used for a 
>   particular stream. It is used for all AVCodecContext and related time 
>   stamps.
>
> **tbr** is guessed from the video stream and is the value users want to see 
>   when they look for the video frame rate, except sometimes it is twice 
>   what one would expect because of field rate versus frame rate.

In the end, you want to take **tbr** as the value one mostly refers to as "framerate".

Bitrate is not always shown as video streams might contain variable bitrate content – in that case, you couldn't really estimate the bitrate. For constant bitrate streams, bitrate is usually shown. There are some cases where variable bitrates are used and FFmpeg shows the average – at least with h.264 video this sometimes works.

<sub>`Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480, 22050 tbr, 22050 tbn, 44100 tbc` seems more like an audio stream, obviously.</sub>